# SSL certificate(letsencrypt) isnot working properly for all servernames

Tags: apache, ssl, mod-rewrite

I am working on my website abcd.xyz and implemented the ssl on it.
The website is working fine with ssl on chrome but has cert problem in safari and chromium(linux) browser

I have redirected the following links to fhttps://abcd.xyz and they worked fine
www.abcd.xyz
abcd.xyz
fhttp://www.abcd.xyz
fhttps://abcd.xyz

but the following ain't working in safari and chromium
(showing the invalid certificate issue)
http://abcd.xyz
https://www.abcd.xyz

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
......
......
     ServerName www.abcd.xyz

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =abcd.xyz [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.abcd.xyz [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.abcd.xyz
RewriteRule ^ https://abcd.xyz%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you pack all your web sites into the same Apache virtual host, you need to bundle all the domain names involved in the same certificate. I don't know whether Let's encrypt offers such feature but your certificate is valid for `zorion.io` only.

The simplest workaround is to create as many virtual hosts as subdomains you host. In each one, specify the appropriate port (I can see you're currently expecting HTTPS on port 80, something that's technically possible but feels completely wrong) and the correct certificate file in the `SSLCertificateFile` directive. Beware though that, unless you have a unique IP/port combination for each host, you may have problems with elderly browsers (old IE versions and some early mobile browsers).